# Sqlite-net in universal app - where is my db?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, sqlite-net

Previously I have used LocalDb in Silverlight apps for Windows Phone 8 which worked great on 8.1 also.

If I wanted to inspect my db, I used the ISETOOL to download the file and attached it in vs.

Management switched me to building a 'universal' app for RT. I am adopting SQLite-net.

In my app, I call:

```
      var db = new SQLiteConnection("Example.db");
      db.CreateTable<SampleModel>();
```

I can see that data is preserved since if I do an insert and then commit and then retrieve in another method it all works.

However, when I use ISETOOL nothing is copied from the emulator to my local folder.

Where is my SQLite db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this, you have to pass the full path to the SqlConnection constructor, like so:

```
var dbFile = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "//Sample.db";
var sql = new SqlConnection(dbFile);
```

Also note that if you're trying to work with SQLite from a portable library, you wouldn't be able to call ApplicationData.Current (very inconvenient). I had to supply this parameter from within executing app.